# what does the *(void**) means

Tags: c++, void

I have seen a class like this on the internet,
the head file

```
#ifndef _COMMON_ARRAY_OBJECT_POOL_H_
#define _COMMON_ARRAY_OBJECT_POOL_H_

#include <stdint.h>

namespace easynet
{

class ArrayObjectPool
{
public:
    /** construct
     * @param elem_size : element size;
     * @param elem_num  : element number
     */
    ArrayObjectPool(uint32_t elem_size, uint32_t elem_num);
    ~ArrayObjectPool();

    uint32_t ElemSize(){return m_ElemSize;}
    uint32_t Capacity(){return m_ElemNum;}
    bool IsEmpty(){return m_FreeHead==NULL;}


    void* Get();


    bool Recycle(void *elem);
private:
    void *m_Elements;
    void *m_End;
    void *m_FreeHead;
    uint32_t m_ElemSize;
    uint32_t m_ElemNum;
};

}
#endif //_COMMON_ARRAY_OBJECT_POOL_H_
```

the cpp file

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "ArrayObjectPool.h"

namespace easynet
{

ArrayObjectPool::ArrayObjectPool(uint32_t elem_size, uint32_t elem_num)
{
    m_ElemNum = elem_num;
    if(elem_size < sizeof(void*))
        m_ElemSize = sizeof(void*);
    else
        m_ElemSize = elem_size;

    m_Elements = malloc(m_ElemSize*m_ElemNum);
    m_End = (void*)((char*)m_Elements+m_ElemSize*m_ElemNum);
    assert(m_Elements != NULL);

    //construct list
    int i;
    void *node = m_Elements;
    for(i=0; i<m_ElemNum-1; ++i)
    {
        *(void**)node = (void*)((char*)node+m_ElemSize);
        node = *(void**)node;
    }
    *(void**)node = NULL;
    m_FreeHead = m_Elements;    //list head
}

ArrayObjectPool::~ArrayObjectPool()
{
    free(m_Elements);
}

void* ArrayObjectPool::Get()
{
    if(m_FreeHead == NULL)
        return NULL;
    void *temp = m_FreeHead;
    m_FreeHead = *(void**)m_FreeHead;
    return temp;
}

bool ArrayObjectPool::Recycle(void *elem)
{
    if(elem<m_Elements || elem>=m_End)
        return false;
    *(void**)elem = m_FreeHead;
    m_FreeHead = elem;
    return true;
}

}
```

**The question is I can't understand what does this means:**

```
int i;
void *node = m_Elements;
for(i=0; i<m_ElemNum-1; ++i)
{
*(void**)node = (void*)((char*)node+m_ElemSize);
node = *(void**)node;
}
```

and what the `*(void**)` means? thanks!

Comment: symbolhound.com works for searches were google fails

http://symbolhound.com/?q=*%28void**%29

Answer (score 2):

It's treating the memory as if it were a `union` between the user's data type, and `void*`.  When the blocks are in the free block list, the `void*` is used.

You can think of it as:

```
union ObjectInObjectPool
{
    void* ptr_next_free_block;
    UserType content;
};
```

and then that loop is basically doing:

```
ObjectInObjectPool* node = m_Elements;
for(i=0; i<m_ElemNum-1; ++i) {
    node->ptr_next_free_block = node + 1;
    node = node->ptr_next_free_block;
}
```

except that the programmer did by hand all the pointer arithmetic that the compiler's type checker usually does.

Comment: Thanks Ben, this do help me to understand this class's fuction.

Answer (score 0):

A `void*` is a pointer value that points to untyped memory. When you do `*(void**)node = ...`, what it is really doing is `*node = ...`. However, with the latter, you are trying to assign something to a `void` which doesn't make sense with C++'s type system; you have to do as in the former and cast it to a `void**` so that `*node` will be a `void*`, not a `void`, and you can assign to it.

`node = *(void**)node` is just `node = *node` but forcing the type system to work. It just does "assign to `node` the value of the memory at `*node` interpreted as a `void*`".

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what the *(void**) means, but what the for loop's function? From my point, it doesn't do anything(*(void**)node = NULL; after for loop), during the for loop  the node pointer plus a m_ElemSize range(eg: 4, 8, 12) every time.